# Can I define the format file in TeX file?

Tags: tex-core, format-files

I have a Finnish format file for TeX.

Can I make TeX use the custom format while processing the file? Looking at `tex -help`, it looks like 
starting the file like: `%&../fin/Finnish.fmt` should work, but nothing changes.

I can make it work with `tex -fmt=../fin/Finnish.fmt`, but I'd like to have this as part of my TeX document.

Comment: The standard  format names (`tex`, `latex`, _etc._) really should not change: you would probably be best defining say `mytex` as a wrapper, which will be OS-dependent.

Comment: I made my own finnish format with hyphenation and finnish characters. For my own use.

Doing tex -help states:
If the first line of TEXNAME is %&FMT, and FMT is an existing .fmt file,
  use it.  Else use `NAME.fmt', where NAME is the program invocation name,
  most commonly `tex'.

It would be clean if the document states the format to use. But I see your point also.

Comment: Try omitting the extension:  `%&.../fin/Finnish`.

Comment: try placing `finnish.fmt` somewhere where your TeX engine can find it (location depends on implementation), and simply use `%&finnish` in your document.

Comment: I am on debian linux, what could be the location to place the Finnish.fmt to? Is it the same location as Tex.fmt

Comment: are you using the command line or some editor? (like Emacs+AUCTeX?)